# What word would I use for the title Lady?

Tags: english-to-german

I have a new puppy that I am registering and want to make sure that I use the proper word for the title "Lady" (noble).

For example: Lady Cassiopeia of Kimbertal

I am not sure if it should be one of the following or something completely different:

- Dame Cassiopeia von Kimbertal
- Herrin Cassiopeia von Kimbertal

I have also seen the word Adlige used but I am not sure that it is used as a title.

Danke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither »*Dame*« nor »*Herrin*« are aristocratic titles.

**Herrin**
In German the word »*Herrin*« often is used as a synonym for »*Domina*« (dominatrix or mistress in the sexual-fetish sense of the word).

**Dame**
The word »*Dame*« can only be used like the English word »*woman*«. It is just a nobler version of »*Frau*«.

If you want to choose a german noble rank, you might find one here: [Adelstitel in Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelstitel). For a female dog I would suggest:

- Gräfin (engl.: countess)
- Freifrau (engl.: baroness)
- Baronin (engl.: baroness)
- Fürstin (engl.: princess)
- Prinzessin (engl.: princess)
- Edle von (engl.: noble of)
- Frau von (engl.: lady)

But it might also be interesting for you, that in German spoken countries many female dogs are named:

> Lady